# How do I search the whole log of a job of a build in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

If I have started a build in Azure DevOps and then select the job, a new screen opens in which the job is logged in the individual steps. How can I search through all the steps in this log screen at once? I find it difficult to click on each individual step ("Auftrag initialisieren", "Set Assembly Manifest Data", ...) and search there with a defined term.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `View raw log` button on the top right side from the picture you posted.
The raw log will give you the logs from all the steps under the `Phase 1` job.

Comment: Thank you Robert, it works. So I have to select the step "Phase 1" and then click on "View raw log" to see the full log.